# MySQL. Subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

I have troubles understanding subqueries. Can someone properly explain it to me please?

I have this query:

```
SELECT substring_index(marca, ' ', 1) AS companie, count(*) AS numar_masini 
FROM tip_masina 
GROUP BY companie;
```

That displays:

```
 companie   numar_masini    
  Chevrolet      5
  Dacia          1
  Dodge          5
  Ford       6
```

And this query:

```
SELECT substring_index(id_masina, ' ', 1) AS marca, SUM(nr_vehicule) AS nr_masini 
FROM proprietate
GROUP BY marca;
```

That displays:

```
 marca  nr_masini   
 Chevrolet     18
 Dodge      9
 Ford      11
```

I want to 'combine' this queries properly and get a result of:

```
  companie  numar_marci  numar_masini   
  Chevrolet      5            18
  Dacia          1             0 (or null)
  Dodge          5             9
  Ford           6            11
```

How can I do that properly? I don't want code, I want a proper explanation of subqueries as I did not understand them properly and I didn't find a proper documentation to explain it to me.

Comment: try using the following link: [MySql subqueries](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-subquery/). If something is not clear you can ask.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET. Also, is the use of a subquery a specific requirement?

Comment: @Strawberry It is not a specific requirement. It was an example so I could learn and understand subqueries better.

Comment: In other words "'yes' it is a specific requirement, because I want to learn about subqueries"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sub query (in this way) is just returning a set of rows. You can treat the result of a sub query as if it were a table.

For example your queries could be used as follows.

```
SELECT b.marca, b.nr_masini, c.numar_masini
(
    SELECT substring_index(id_masina, ' ', 1) AS marca, SUM(nr_vehicule) AS nr_masini 
    FROM proprietate
    GROUP BY marca
) b
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT substring_index(marca, ' ', 1) AS companie, count(*) AS numar_masini 
    FROM tip_masina 
    GROUP BY companie
) c
ON b.marca = c.companie
```

Here it is taking your first query and getting the 4 makes (with the counts to go with them), then joining that result against the result of your 2nd query. You 2nd query only brings back 3 rows.

Possibly that both queries could return rows that the other query doesn't return. In which case you might use a 3rd sub query to get the main rows. Then you can join the other 2 against that:-

```
SELECT a.companie, b.nr_masini, c.numar_masini
FROM
(
    SELECT substring_index(marca, ' ', 1) AS companie
    FROM tip_masina 
    UNION
    SELECT substring_index(id_masina, ' ', 1) AS companie
    FROM proprietate
) a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT substring_index(id_masina, ' ', 1) AS marca, SUM(nr_vehicule) AS nr_masini 
    FROM proprietate
    GROUP BY marca
) b
ON a.companie = b.marca
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT substring_index(marca, ' ', 1) AS companie, count(*) AS numar_masini 
    FROM tip_masina 
    GROUP BY companie
) b
ON a.companie = c.companie
```

In this way you are using one sub query to get a list of all the possible companie values, and treating that as a table to join against the other 2 sub queries.

You could set up each of these sub queries as a view which would make them look even more like tables when you join them.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a subquery. `substring_index` is a function.

This is how a subquery works.

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (
     -- This is the subquery
     SELECT id, test1, test2 
     FROM table
    ) TableAlias
```

Basically, mysql collects the result from the inner select:

```
SELECT id, test1, test2 FROM table
```

is now the `TableAlias`

So the syntax can be used like this now

```
SELECT TableAlias.Id, TableAlias.test1, TableAlias.test2 
FROM
    (
     -- This is the subquery
     SELECT id, test1, test2 
     FROM table
    ) TableAlias
```

Subqueries are useful for many things. Like when using aggergated functions like `SUM`, `AVG`. Then it can really help to `ORDER` reuslts.

Try this link: http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/mysql/w/wiki/6355.table-subqueries.aspx

I hope that explains Subqueries a little bit better for you.